# How do I prove the multivariable limit $\max\{ \frac{1}{\sqrt n} -\frac{\sqrt m}{ n},\frac{\sqrt n}{m} -\frac{1}{ \sqrt m}\}\to 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, multivariable-calculus, double-sequence

While proving that $C([0,1])$ whith the norm $\|f\|=\sup_{t\in [0,1]}(t|f(t)|)$ is not complete
the tutor used the following sequence:

$x_n(t)=\cases{\frac{1}{\sqrt t}, t\in [\frac{1}{n},1]\\ \sqrt n , t \in [0,\frac{1}{ n}]} $
And he proved it is Cauchy:

[image: ![enter image description here]

$\forall n>m$:

$\|x_n-x_m\|=\sup_{t\in [0,1]}(t|x_n(t)-x_m(t)|)$

$=\max\{ \sup_{t\in [0,1/n]}(t(\sqrt n - \sqrt m)),\sup_{t\in [1/n,1/m]}(t(\frac{1}{\sqrt t }- \sqrt m)),0\}$

$\le \max\{ \frac{1}{n}(\sqrt n - \sqrt m),\frac{1}{m}(\sqrt n- \sqrt m)\}  = \max\{ \frac{1}{\sqrt n} -\frac{\sqrt m}{ n},\frac{\sqrt n}{m} -\frac{1}{ \sqrt m}\}\to 0$

**How do I prove that limit is zero step by step?**  I don't know how to deal with the max and how to take the multivariable limit.

My questions are:

**1 Since the max of continuous functions is a continuous function , is it true that**

$\lim_{(n,m)\to(\infty,\infty)}\max(f(n,m),g(n,m))=\max(\lim_{(n,m)\to(\infty,\infty)}  f(n,m), \lim_{(n,m)\to(\infty,\infty)}  g(n,m))$ ?

**2 How do I find  the multivariable limit ?** I feel like taking first the limit as$ n \to \infty$ (holding m constant) and the limit as $ m \to \infty$ in the first element of the max and the other way around for the second element wouldn't be correct since it is well-known that the multivariable limit is different than the iterated limit.

[image]

Comment: I am concerned about this multivariable limit. It appears to only hold for certain paths of approach, and thus not in general. If you just let $n\to\infty$ first, your maximum will be tending also toward $\infty$

Comment: @FShrike Assuming We can take limits on each element of the max separately, when letting $n \to \infty$ first only on the first element would yield zero and when letting  $m \to \infty$ first for the second element would yield zero as well, but I am unsure this is correct, first that would be an iterated limit right? The plot also seems to suggest it is not correct. Perhaps the professor though of it in this naive way

Comment: Well, if the multivariable limit exists then so too does the iterated limit, and indeed the iterated limit would equal the multi-limit. This is because the multi-limit must be the same regardless of the path of approach

Comment: I note that you defined $x$ on interval $[0,1/\sqrt{n}]$ but use $1/n$ in your workings.

Comment: @FShrike Oops, fixed that typo, thanks for catching that

Comment: It is more than a typo - I haven't looked closely, but it could have strong implications on the validity of the result! Furthermore, I'm not at all convinced the last entry in the max should be $0$

Comment: @FShrike The $ 0$ comes from $f_n = f_m$, in $[1/m,1]$ as in the plot I just uploaded (n>m)

Comment: I misread $\sqrt{t}$ as again $\sqrt{n}$, apologies

Comment: $\max\{ \frac{1}{n}(\sqrt n - \sqrt m),\frac{1}{m}(\sqrt n- \sqrt m)\}=\frac{1}{m}(\sqrt n- \sqrt m)$ So I just have to study this limit.

Comment: @FShrike As you observed if I let $n \to \infty$ first the iterated limit is $\infty$, while letting $m \to \infty$ first yields 0 as limit. Therefore the double limit can not exist, makes sense as a proof? Therefore the proof I was given should be wrong

Comment: This i supposing the existence of a double limit, implies the equality of the iterated limit, but I can't find a reference for that

Comment: I have never really worked with multi variable limits but I can be very confident that if the limit does not exist on one path of approach (namely as $n\to\infty$) then it does not exist. You should ask your professor for clarification - perhaps you miscopied their notes or the professor made an honest mistake

Comment: the problem was actually solved by a tutor, a student of last year's course, so the probability of error is greater, but the solution is identical to that of the year before solved by another tutor from  he followed the course, so I think he is just learned the same potentially incorrect solution. Sadly the professor is one that never answers you emails so hope someone can answer this

Answer (score 1):

Replacing $\sup_{t\in [1/n,1/m]}(t(\frac{1}{\sqrt t }- \sqrt m))$ by the weaker upper bound $\frac{1}{m}(\sqrt n- \sqrt m)$ kills the proof because, for example, with $n=2m^2$ the expression grows beyond every bound.

A more sensible approach observes that $\max_{t\in [0,1/m]}(t(\frac{1}{\sqrt t }- \sqrt m))=\frac1{2m}(1-\frac1{2 \sqrt m})$ at $t=\frac1{4m^2}$.

Comment: With $n=2m^2$we have that $ \frac{1}{m}(\sqrt n- \sqrt m)=\frac{1}{m}(\sqrt (2n^2)- \sqrt m)=\sqrt 2 -\frac{1}{\sqrt m}$ $\to 0$, why do say it grows beyond every bound?

Comment: and why are taking the max over [0,1/m] instead of in [1/n,1/m]?

Comment: The boundlessness was my mistake (an earlier version used $n=m^3).$.

Comment: The choice of $[0,1]$ was easier and proved to be sufficient.

Comment: You are upper-bounding the sup over [1/n,1/m] with the sup over [0,1/m] using the fact that the sup made over a superset  is greater than or equal than that over the initial set?

Comment: The derivative of $t(\frac{1}{\sqrt t}-\sqrt m)$ is $0 $at $t=1/4m$, and replacing that into the equation yields a max is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt m}$

Comment: that with take care of the second term, but I still need to bound$ \sup_{t\in [0,1/n]}(t(\sqrt n - \sqrt m)) $with something depending on only one variable in order to take limits without trouble

Comment: You do not need that. Cauchy only requires  that for every $\varepsilon >0$ one has $\|x_n-x_m\|\lt \varepsilon$ if n and m are both greater then some N.

Comment: I don't follow you, we are working with $\max\{ \sup_{t\in [0,1/n]}(t(\sqrt n - \sqrt m)),\sup_{t\in [1/n,1/m]}(t(\frac{1}{\sqrt t }- \sqrt m)),0\}$, trying to bound it, you have shown how to bound the second term inside the max, but the first one still has to be accounted for

Comment: Direct evaluation  with t=1/n doesn't help as we'd have $1/\sqrt n - \sqrt m/n$. An the second radical is problematic, since it grows without bound as you observed similarly with the other term

Answer (score 0):

By construction of answer $\frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{m}$, i.e., $n>m$, so $\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{m} \leq 2 \sqrt{n}$. Thus we get from your second last step
$$=max\{2\sqrt{n}/n, 2\sqrt{n}/m \}.$$
By Archimedian property, there exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $km>n ~ => ~ \frac{1}{m}<\frac{k}{n}$ thus above is less or equal to
$$ \leq max\{\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}},\frac{2k}{\sqrt{n}} \}$$ which goes to zero

Comment: I am not very convinced about  how you did this $\max\{\frac{1}{n}(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{m}), \frac{1}{m}(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{m}) \} \leq max\{\frac{1}{n}(2\sqrt{n}), \frac{1}{m}(2\sqrt{m}) \}  $. I think it should be  $\max\{\frac{1}{n}(2\sqrt{n}), \frac{1}{m}(2\sqrt{n}) \} . $ And shouldn't we used $n\ge m$? so it reduces to $\max\{\frac{1}{n}(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{m}), \frac{1}{m}(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{m}) \} \le 2\frac{\sqrt n}{m}$ and the problems persists

Comment: You are right. Thanks, i tried to edit.

Comment: I am not very sure but I think the same problem persists as when I reduced $\max\{2\sqrt{n}/n, 2\sqrt{n}/m \}= 2\sqrt{n}/m $ using $n > m$. I think$ k$ is a function of $m$ and$ n$, so why should it stay constant when taking the double limit? It's like hiding the problem inside k.

Comment: The only path along which a natural number approach to infinity is x-axis, so i think you can take n=km,..this is how double limits are taken. We check every path (x,y) approaches to (a,b)